# Memory Error While Saving Ubuntu's Status before Closing

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, ram

After trying to save the Ubuntu status before closing the operating system (which is installed on a VirtualBox machine on a host windows), here is the error message I receive resulting in the closing of ubuntu and not saving its status. I would appreciate if someone can explain this and give a solution for it.

> The instruction at  ************************** referenced memory at *******************************. The memory
>   could not be read. Click OK to terminate the program.

Where stars stand for some weird combination of letters and numbers.

NOTE:
I have allocated ~10,000 MB as Base Memory with 1 CPU processor.

Comment: How much RAM have you allocated to the Ubuntu VM? How many CPUs?

Comment: Just added those info in the last line. Is that what you meant?

Comment: How much real physical RAM do you have? Assuming that you have 4 or more physical CPU cores available, try setting the VM for 2 CPU's and 2048 RAM. Report back.

Comment: Heynnema, thank you. I added 2 more CPU. Now it's 3 of them. Plus my real physical RAM is 10747 Mib. But the issue is still there.

Comment: But that's the problem. You've allocated ALL of your physical RAM to the VM. Try setting the VM as I recommended earlier... 2 CPU and 2048 RAM.

Comment: But I tried that. Still not working:(

Comment: What version VB? Have you installed Guest Additions?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. And it seems I cannot install Guest Additions for some reason.

Comment: What version VB? What happens when you install GA? How are you doing it?

Comment: I am doing it through Devices-->Insert Guest Additions. But I am receiving error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97516/discussion-between-allan-and-heynnema).